# How to disable resizing of a multi-window activity

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, multi-window

I have just added multi-window support to my application. I have two Activities A and B, where A starts B. And I would like to disable resizing(or disable multiwindow) of activity B. Setting `android:resizeableActivity=false` doesn't work. It only works if both A and B are set to false [commonsblog](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/06/17/opting-out-multi-window-hard.html).

Comment: Is activity B "exported"? It seems to me that having only one "exported" activity (the launcher = not activity B?) should keep you on the safe side

Comment: @0X0nosugar no it's not an exported activity.